# Centering header content divs

Tags: html, css

I’m having trouble centering the divs named ‘one’ and ‘two’. They need to retain their styles exactly as they are which keep them side by side and margins but also be centered which is the bit I can’t work out?

Also the nav divs need to be centered which I have achieved with the styles below.

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width:300px;
  height:auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom:1px solid  #ccc;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
#header #one {
  font: 1.625em "Arial Black", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:100;
  float: left;
  color:#95061e;
  margin-bottom:10px;
 }
#header #two {
  font:1.625em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  float:left;
  margin-top:3px;
  margin-left:3px;
  margin-right:5px;
  color:#953606;
 }
```

```html
  <div id="header">
    <div id="one">Birch</div>
    <div id="two">Wood</div>
      <div class="nav_active"><A href="#"></A></div>
      <div class="nav_inactive"><A href="#"></A></div>
      <div class="nav_inactive"><A href="#"></A></div>
      <div class="nav_inactive"><A href="#"></A></div>
      <div class="nav_inactive"><A href="#"></A></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What about the navigation links `a`? It is not clear what your layout is expected to look like.

Comment: You can use a wrapper and give it a width and make it center using margin auto; : check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/upmcjr64/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;`.

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width:300px;
  height:auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom:1px solid  #ccc;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
#header #one {
  font: 1.625em "Arial Black", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:100;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#95061e;
  margin-bottom:10px;
 }
#header #two {
  font:1.625em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:3px;
  margin-left:3px;
  margin-right:5px;
  color:#953606;
 }
```

```html
  <div id="header">
    <div id="one">Birch</div>
    <div id="two">Wood</div>
      <div class="nav_active"><A href="#"></A></div>
      <div class="nav_inactive"><A href="#"></A></div>
      <div class="nav_inactive"><A href="#"></A></div>
      <div class="nav_inactive"><A href="#"></A></div>
      <div class="nav_inactive"><A href="#"></A></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
#header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom:1px solid  #ccc;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header #one {
        font: 1.625em "Arial Black", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight:100;
        color:#95061e;
        margin-bottom:10px;display:inline-block;
    }
#header #two {
        font:1.625em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;margin-top:3px;
    display:inline-block;
        color:#953606;
    }
```

jsfiddle link [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/10Ljhfnh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the floating in your css, as shown here.
https://jsfiddle.net/dy8bzuv3/

If you want to have both divs in a single line, simply add `display:inline;` to your css rules for `#one` and also `#two`

Answer (score 0):

Good luck on your learning journey! The change I've made here is the `#one` and `#two` divs are being given `display:inline`. This will treat them similar to text, so the text-align option applies to them.

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width:300px;
  height:auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom:1px solid  #ccc;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
#header #one {
  font: 1.625em "Arial Black", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:100;
  color:#95061e;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  display: inline;
 }
#header #two {
  font:1.625em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top:3px;
  margin-left:3px;
  margin-right:5px;
  color:#953606;
  display: inline;
 }
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="one">Birch</div>
    <div id="two">Wood</div>
      <div class="nav_active"><A href="#"></A></div>
      <div class="nav_inactive"><A href="#"></A></div>
      <div class="nav_inactive"><A href="#"></A></div>
      <div class="nav_inactive"><A href="#"></A></div>
      <div class="nav_inactive"><A href="#"></A></div>
  </div>
```